# how to fetch createdAt from parse and append to an array - swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I successfully fetched values from parse and storing them into an array

```
var dataSource: [PFObject] = []
```

and when I append createdAt values from parse which is a NSDate data type.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate!' to expected argument type 'PFObject'
```

with this code

```
self.dataSource.append(object.createdAt as NSDate!)
```

here's the whole code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,      cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "JobsTVCellIdentifier"
    let cell:JobsTVCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? JobsTVCell

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser)
    }
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    let objects = query.findObjects()
    for object in (objects as? [PFObject])!{
        //print(object.objectId)
        self.dataSource.append(object)
        self.dataSource.append(object.createdAt as NSDate!)
//            let genderValues = object["gender"] as! String
//            print(genderValues)
//            let dateValues = object.createdAt
//            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
//            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'"
//            var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateValues!)
//            cell?.createdAt.text = strDate
        print(dataSource)
        let itemArr:PFObject = self.dataSource[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        cell?.genderTextfield.text = itemArr["gender"] as! String
        cell?.occupationTextfield.text = itemArr["occupation"] as! String

    }
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append createdAt property which is NSDate to array of PFObjects, and that doesn't work.

You have 2 options:

1) create array of NSDates like so:

```
var dataSource: [NSDate] = []
```

and append that property to it.

2) append whole object to PFObject array and then read createdAt property:

```
dataSource.append(object)
let createdAt = dataSource["createdAt"]
```

Comment: I tried it and it successfully stored all the dates inside the new array[NSdate], now the problem is I can't show the value in my label.text using indexPath

Comment: Your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is a mess .. you need to move your networking actions inside of another class/function and you dont need for .. in in it .. if you need to show createdAt field just under the cell definition write cell?.textLabel.text = datasource[indexPath.row].createdAt as! String

Comment: do you mind updating your answer about network actions inside another class/function. but I need to store first data from parse to my array that's why I do have a for loop for to create an object. after storing the NSDate values from parse, I need to convert it to String and show it to label.text

Comment: As Kristijan says, you need to move the network activity (i.e. the Parse query) out side cellForRowAtIndexPath. Create a method `getObjectsFromParse()`or similar, where you fetch your data. At the end of the query you can put `tableView.reloadData()`, and reload your table with the arrays that you filled with data from Parse. Make sure your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `yourArray.count`.